# Pickle / Save Virtual File in Python to Disk

Tags: python, pickle, graph-tool, virtual-file

I would like to pickle a virtual file within a dictionary.

Specifically, I have a [function](https://graph-tool.skewed.de/static/doc/graph_tool.html#graph_tool.Graph.save) `G` with a method `save()` that takes a file-obj or a string (filename) to save it's content to disk.

But I would like to save it to a *virtual* file first, then put this virtual file into a `dict` together with associate data and then save (pickle) the complete dictionary to disk.

How can I save to an in-memory file, include it in a dictionary and pickle that? Or how would you do it?

Something like:

```py
out = {
    'var1': var1,
    'var2': var2
    }

with tempfile.SpooledTemporaryFile() as file:

    G.save(file)
    out['G'] = file
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why do you want to save the file, and not the class G itself?

Comment: Because G itself is not picklable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want to do should be possible by the following:

```
out = {
    'var1': var1,
    'var2': var2
    }

with tempfile.SpooledTemporaryFile() as file:
    G.save(file)
    file.seek(0) # reset the file handle to the start
    out['G'] = file.read() # read the binary data into your dict
```

The binary stream can later be converted back to a file-like obj. using `io.BytesIO( out['G'] )`.

Comment: Awesome, this seems to work! `.seek(0)` and `.read()` are the missing parts.